# Find summary in group wise under report footer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my crystal report i have used grouping.in each group there are some services name with its corresponding amount.Now i want to find out the sumary of each services in report footer.
The report may look like this.

```
Group A
.......
abc : 100
xyz  :200

Group B
.......
abc : 200
xyz  :200
axd  :100
..........

Summary
abc  :300
xyz  :400
axd  :100
```

How do do this.please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Insert a `Subreport` in the main Report Footer Section
   Select `Create a subreport`, select connection, command or tables and links, fields, `Grouping` by `Services` field, `Summary` by `Amount` field (as Sum). Define record selection criteria and also `Link` main report with subreport
2. If grouping not defined while creating report then use `Group Expert` to insert groups as per `Services` (only by `Services` field, do not group here by `Group A, B` etc.)
3. Add summary to the `Services` group in the Group Footer Section (`Sum` of `Services` field)
4. `Suppress` the Details Section
5. Format your Subreport Group Footer accordingly.